# How do I add checkboxes to Magento's "Estimate Shipping and Tax" in the cart?

Tags: magento

So, on the cart page, my customers can view the "Estimate Shipping and Tax" area.  I don't want to remove it, but I need to know a little additional information from them to properly process the shipping.  For example, on a freight item, I need to know if they have a loading dock.

Currently, I do this in the checkout without any issue.  I was able to check if there is a freight item, and, if so, show the checkboxes to the customer during the "Shipping Address" stage.  Then, in the saveShipping function, I was able to pull in the values and pass them to the shipping charge calculation.

Well, I've got the checkboxes in the template to display in the "Estimate Shipping and Tax" when there is a freight item in the cart, but I don't know much about the coShippingMethodForm function so that I can add in the values of the checkboxes.  Anyone have any idea where I should be looked for this?

Additionally, when I hit "Get estimate", the page refreshes and it removes their selections.  How best can I retain their selections to repopulate the correct boxes once the page refreshes?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the best way would be to write your own shipping method module. I personally would steer clear of having a checkbox added to 'Estimate shipping and taxes' instead in my module I'd output both prices with loading bay, without loading bay (just for the estimates) in checkout you can get that option from the "Shipping Address" section and pass it into you shipping module calculation this is just a little 'cleaner.'

Check out this wiki for how to write a custom shipping module http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module

Comment: Hi Alan - I'm sorry I wasn't clear.  It's not as simple as creating a shipping module.  We actually have created a freight shipping "module" already - I put it in quotes, because its not a module in the traditional sense.  It's more like a layer that sits on top of the basic UPS, FedEx, etc. - the other shipping modules because any order could be comprised of multiple types of items, and it didn't make sense to create a module that encompassed everything that was already done.

Comment: I do like your suggestion about defaults though - unfortunately, I can't put the prices for each combination - there would be dozens, but most customers will fit into a single getup (i.e. with a loading dock), so I think I'll show that as the default and then urge them to go through the checkout if they have a different scenario (the checkout works fine, allowing them to select if they have a loading dock, need a liftgate, etc.) Thanks!